# Programmatically executing a query cannot find the entry. In SQL Developer works

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I have a very strange behavior when I execute e query from Java code with Hibernate and when I call the same query directly from SQL Developer.
In the first case the entry could not be found but in the second case it is found.

1st case (Java code query):

```
getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("SELECT MAX(VERSION) FROM TIME_VERSION WHERE DIRECTORY=1").getResultList();
```

returns null.

2nd case (SQL Developer query):

```
SELECT MAX(VERSION) 
FROM TIME_VERSION 
WHERE DIRECTORY=1;
```

returns a value.

Important: A more strange behavior, is that, if I will edit any column value
from this entry (ex. VERSION) with SQL Developer and then I try to execute again the

Java Query from inside the code, it works correctlly and returns the same result as the query from the SQL Developer.

Does anybody knows why happens such a behaviour and what could be done to avoid it?

P.S. TIME_VERSION table has 7 Columns and a custom primary key. The database is an Oracle DB.

Comment: *"A more strange behavior, is that, if I will edit any column value from this entry (ex. VERSION) with SQL Developer "*  That sounds like your Hibernate code is caching an null result set somewhere, until you force a refresh. But I don't know Hibernate so I can't tell you how to diagnose that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did found the problem:

When I was adding this entry in the database I had not done a commit at the end. I don't know why if you make a search query inside SQL Developer it will be found (even without the commit) but if you make a search from some external environment (like Java Hibernate) it will not be found! Maybe there is a more professional answer.

Solution: I just made a `commit;` at the end (after the insert query) and now is functioning correctly.

Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

As your query is returning a single result, can you try

```
getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(
    "SELECT MAX(VERSION) FROM TIME_VERSION WHERE DIRECTORY=1").getSingleResult()
```